# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (64, 64, 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Basically I was following this machine learning A-Z tutorials from udemy where I learned to train my own convolutional neural network model however I wasn't shown how to use that trained model - how to give an input and get an output. I checked out some tutorials on youtube to pass a single image through a cnn in Keras and came along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watchv=A4K6D_gx2Iw&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN&index=6) tutorial. When I did run the code I got an error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (64, 64, 1)

and now I've no clue how to deal with this problem at all. If someone could tell me what to do after ive trained my networks and how to go about this whole problem ill be really grateful ive tried changing     `img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`
to read color but I think that's got nothing to do with this

My code that I used to train my convolutional network :

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
```

**initializing the cnn**
`classifier = Sequential()`

**step1- applying convolution**

```
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, border_mode = 'same', input_shape=(64,64,3), activation = 'relu'))
```

**apply max pooling**

```
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

**adding another convolutional layer for better accuracy**

```
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, border_mode = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

**applying flattening**

```
classifier.add(Flatten())
```

**Step 4 - Full connection**

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
#input
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
#output
```

**compile it all**

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
#fitting the cnn to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#pixels take values between 0 & 255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,                        
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set', target_size=(64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')       
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                         target_size=(64, 64),
                                         batch_size=32,
                                         class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     samples_per_epoch = 8000,
                     nb_epoch = 25,
                     verbose = 1,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     nb_val_samples = 2000)

classifier.save('my_model.h5')
```

---

code I used in a new file to try out my trained network

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential

Categories = ["Dogs","cats"]

def prepare(filepath):
    img_size = 64
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))
    return new_array.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size, 1)
    classifier = keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')

prediction = classifier.predict([prepare('/Users/m.zain/Documents/machine learning-2019 dps/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)/dog.jpg')])
print(prediction)

prediction = classifier.predict([prepare('/Users/m.zain/Documents/machine learning-2019 dps/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)/dog.jpg')])
 print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])

prediction = classifier.predict([prepare('/Users/m.zain/Documents/machine learning-2019 dps/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)/cat.jpg')])
 print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

---

I expected to get "dog" as an output when I executed the code:

```
prediction = classifier.predict([prepare('/Users/m.zain/Documents/machine learning-2019 dps/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)/dog.jpg')])
print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

and cat as an output when I ran this:

```
prediction = classifier.predict([prepare('/Users/m.zain/Documents/machine learning-2019 dps/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)/cat.jpg')])
print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Comment: Obviously, you are loading grayscale images. They have only one channel. Load rgb images instead, they have three.

Comment: I removed the cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and changed (-1,img_size,img_size, 3) and now it works fine ...but is there any way to increase my efficiency? the machine is predicting both images to be cats